# Taylor expansion of a square root

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, taylor-expansion

I was trying to understand the solution of an exercise, when I read this passage. The book is able to expand:

$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+(y'(x)+y''(x)dx)^2}}
$$

in

$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+y'(x)^2}}\left(1-\frac{y'(x)y''(x)dx}{1+y'(x)^2}\right)
$$

Where $y$ is a function of $x$ and $dx$ is the differential of $x$. 
It only says: "Expanding the square root to first order in $dx$".
I don't understand how.

Can someone explain this passage to me?
Thanks a lot

Dave!

Here are all the references:
The problem is from "David, Morin, Introductory classical mechanics", page I-19, that is problem 8 of chapter 1.

The text of the problem:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6GXR.png)

The solution of the problem:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJNrQ.png)(https://i.stack.imgur.com/KugIo.png)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/xx4AW.png)

However, I don't need someone explaining me the problem, but only the central passage of the expansion to the first order. I hope the pictures I added will be helpful.

Comment: Looks strange to have $dx$ in the denominator, and on some terms but not others.  Questions that merely say "The book" are often impossible to answer.

Comment: Would it be better if I post a picture of the page of the book? However, it makes a lot of approximations, and even only a starting piece of advicefrom the first equation would help me.

Comment: What is equation $1.38$? What is the name of the textbook and what page are you referencing?

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. Now I posted all the references and the pictures both of the text and the solution of the problem

Comment: You'll see $dx$ used (abused) this way sometimes in physics texts, but it's certainly better practice to use the notation $\Delta x$ instead.

Comment: So $dx$ is like the $(x-x_0)$ term of the first order expansion?

Comment: It's related---just think of $dx$ as a very small quantity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually compute the series for $f(u) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{a + u}}$ to first order:
$$f(u) \sim f(0) + f'(0) u + O(u^2) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{a}} \left(1 - \frac{u}{2 a} + O(u^2) \right).$$

This is just the first-order truncation of the [binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series) for $f$ (for appropriate choices of $a$ and $u$).